# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python

Tags: python, mapreduce

`list[s]` is a string. Why doesn't this work?

The following error appears:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

```
list = ['abc', 'def']
map_list = []

for s in list:
  t = (list[s], 1)
  map_list.append(t)
```

Comment: please don't use list as a name, it's a shadow of python built-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = ['abc', 'def']
list2=[]
for t in list1:
    for h in t:
        list2.append(h)
map_list = []        
for x,y in enumerate(list2):
    map_list.append(x)
print (map_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

This is what you want exactly.

> If you dont want to reach each element then:

```
list1 = ['abc', 'def']
map_list=[]
for x,y in enumerate(list1):
    map_list.append(x)
print (map_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[0, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: I downvoted because this does not explain why the original code did not work or where the error in the OP's understanding was.

Answer (score 14):

When you iterate over a list, the loop variable receives the actual list elements, not their indices. Thus, in your example `s` is a string (first `abc`, then `def`).

It looks like what you're trying to do is essentially this:

```
orig_list = ['abc', 'def']
map_list = [(el, 1) for el in orig_list]
```

This is using a Python construct called [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 6):

Do not use the name `list` for a list. I have used `mylist` below.

```
for s in mylist:
    t = (mylist[s], 1)
```

`for s in mylist:` assigns elements of `mylist` to `s` i.e `s` takes the value 'abc' in the first iteration and 'def' in the second iteration. Thus, `s` can't be used as an index in `mylist[s]`.

Instead, simply do:

```
for s in lists:
    t = (s, 1)
    map_list.append(t)
print map_list
#[('abc', 1), ('def', 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
for s in my_list:     # here s is element  of list not index of list
    t = (s, 1)
    map_list.append(t)
```

i think you want:

```
for i,s in enumerate(my_list):  # here i is the index and s is the respective element
    t = (s, i)
    map_list.append(t)
```

`enumerate` give index and element

Note: using list as variable name is bad practice. its built in function

Answer (score 0):

`for s in list` will produce the items of the list and not their indexes. So `s` will be `'abc'` for the first loop, and then 
`'def'`. `'abc'` could only be a key to a dict, not a list index.

In the line with `t` fetching the item by index is redundant in python.