# The TypeError in python

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.6

I'm trying to make a challenge for one of the courses I'm following. I'm new to programming, but I'm eager to learn.
Can you tell me in detail why this error occurs to me and how do solve it.

```
default_names =['Justin', 'john','Emilee', 'jim','Ron','Sandra','veronica','Wiskley']
i=0
for i in default_names:
    default_names[i]=default_names[i][0].upper()
    i+=1
    if i==len(default_names):
        break

print default_names
```

the error: **TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str**

Comment: Did you try looking this up before asking the question? There are tons of similar questions on the Python tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667531/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-python)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is :

```
for i,s in enumerate(default_names):
```

or simple:

```
for i in range(len(default_names)):
```

The mistake you are doing is that when you say `for i in default_names:` notice that `i` value is a string, not `int` as you are trying to use.

```
for i in default_names:
     print(i)
```

Will give :

```
OUT: Justin
     john
     Emilee
     jim
     Ron
     Sandra
     veronica
     Wiskley
```

So the actual code should be, assuming you are trying to convert each string in list to Upper case :

```
for i in range(len(default_names)):
    default_names[i]=default_names[i].upper()
```

**EDIT :** The OP wants only First char to be Upper case, and since `string` are immutable, change of code to :

```
for i in range(len(default_names)): 
     default_names[i]=default_names[i][0].upper() + default_names[i][1:]
```

Comment: actually try the first letter for each name to be the upper. And btw thank you for your answer

Comment: Just change `default_names[i]` to `default_names[i][0]`. And sure, glad to help.

Comment: thank you for your help and I'm sorry if the questions were stupid I'm trying to learn and improve myself.

Comment: Its fine @Dallasboy , everyone's got to start from somewhere. A suggestion though : try **Googling** your problems before you opt for asking in SO. The community here is helpful but a bit stingy too if we don't see enough work from the OP's side.

Answer (score 0):

```
default_names =['Justin', 'john','Emilee', 'jim','Ron','Sandra','veronica','Wiskley']

for i in range(len(default_names)):
    default_names[i]=default_names[i].upper()

print default_names
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str. It's because to access the elements of a list, you have to use the index, which is an integer. Basing on the structure of your code, you might have come from a different language. Python's for loop is different from the other languages. It doesn't increment the variable you made over the loop, but rather it iterates over the elements and passes the value to the variable. I think it would be more suitable to use a while loop with the code you made since you have initialized your i to 0. E.g.

```
default_names =['Justin', 'john','Emilee', 'jim','Ron','Sandra','veronica','Wiskley']
i=0
while i < len(default_names):
    default_names[i]=default_names[i].upper() #removed the [0] here
    i+=1
    #removed the other codes here
print default_names
```

As you become better in python, you can find more efficient ways to do these kinds of things. The result you wanted could be simply made through

> `default_names = [name.upper() for name in default_names]`

which simply iterates all of the names, makes it upper case and saves it back to default_names