# Not able to extract my friend images from Facebook API using python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got this response from the Facebook Graph API:

```
{
   "taggable_friends": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "Friend1 Name",
            "picture": {
               "data": {
                  "url": "https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/completeUrl1"
               }
            },
            "id": "response1d"
         },
         {
            "name": "Friend2 name",
            "picture": {
               "data": {
                  "url": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/completeURL2"
               }
            },
            "id": "responseid2"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "before": "xyz",
            "after": "abc"
         },
         "next": "NextpageURl"
      }
   },
   "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I am willing to extract the URL part of the graph API response with field `taggable_friends`.

I have tried something like this:

```
for friends in data_json_liked_pages['taggable_friends']['data']:
    friend_url = friends['picture']['data']['url']
    print friend_url
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value:  list indices must be integers, not str

What can I do to improve this?

Comment: did you google for the error? there are a lot of threads about it on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Yes I did. I have even checked many on the stackoverflow. But were not of any use.. I tried.. If you can suggest any and if that is not visited by me then I can tell you regarding it for sure.. but don't know where I missed.

Comment: side question: may i ask for for exactly you need to get the profile pictures of friends?

Comment: Your code works with the data you have provided. Can you please print the content of data_json_liked_pages before the for loop?

Comment: how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667531/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-python

Comment: @luschn I am trying to display my friends list and for that I am using there profile picture given by graph api.

Comment: @luschn I have already gone through this thread. Actually this was the thread that the Stackoverflow suggested while I was typing the question.. but it didn't work

Comment: `print(data_json_liked_pages)` and update the question with the result

Comment: @mentalita ok I will insert a gist in the question as a response form the api

Comment: ok, but WHAT FOR do you want to display your friends? do you want to tag friends?

Comment: I am just using the api for the experiment to get my profile from the api + my friends with images and name + the likes pages This is what I am doing. No scraping ... no vandalisms nothing it is just or show.