# How to load data from multiple JSON files from a list using python?

Tags: python, json, list, file

Essentially, I have a list of JSON files that I need information extracted from which is saved in a variable called `json_files`.

The information from these files needs to then be aggregated and transferred into a new file called `summary.json`.

Currently, I am able to do this with the following lines of code but only for one file at a time by specifying an index:

```
with open(json_files[1]) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

However, if I try using a for loop like as follows, I get a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slicers, not str

```
for i in json_files:
    with open(json_files[i]) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

Thus, I was wondering what would be the best way to load information from multiple json files and then combine that into 1 new large json file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `i` here isn't an index, it's the actual _value_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667531/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-python)

Comment: Try to use the range() function to iterate over the list, by setting range to the length of list.
For error :  You get the error because for loop is returning the element of list, not index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in json_files:
    with open(json_files[i]) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Should be

```
for i in json_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

What's happening: `json_files` is a list with names I'm assuming, so something like `json_files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json']`

So your open method was getting parameters like `json_files['file1.json']` within the for loop which doesn't make sense since json_files is a list and not a dictionary.

The `i` in the for loop holds the actual **value** in the list, not the **indexes**.

Edit:

The `data` variable in the above code is being overwritten in each iteration of the loop! You probably need to do something like this to fix it:

```
combined = []
    for i in json_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            combined.append(json.load(f))
```

And then use the `dump` function to write this list into another file.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this change only loads and dumps the information in the last file of the list. How can I copy and transfer the information of every file in the list to the same new file?

Comment: Ah, that's because the data variable is being overwritten by each iteration of the loop, so only the last value is held in that one when its used as a parameter for the dump function. I've edited my answer to give you some idea of how I would fix this.